# NSData appendBytes equivalent

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I haven't found any get equivalent to appendBytes. If I've understood getBytes correctly, that method always returns bytes from the *start* of the buffer. It will not increment.

What's the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods that give you access to some part of the data in a NSData object. For example, you can use `-getBytes:range:` to copy the data specified by a NSRange into a buffer. Or you can use `-subdataWithRange:` to get a NSData that contains just a portion of another.

If you want to read sequentially through the contents of a NSData object, you can create a NSInputStream and initialize it with your NSData, and then read from the stream using `-getBuffer:length:` or `-read:maxLength:`.

```
NSInputStream *stream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:myData];
[stream open];
while ([stream read:&buffer maxLength:bufferLength] > 0) {
    // do something with buffer
}
```

Note: you obviously don't need the `while` loop in the code above if you're not doing the same thing to each chunk of data that you read -- I just included it because it's a common way to read data.

Comment: That NSInputStream solution is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: I tried that stream solution, but it didn't work as expected. The uncommented works, but the commented equivalent(?) does not.
`-(void) importPackedData: (NSData*) data
{
  if (data.length >= sizeof(TransportBlockHeaderS))
  {
    //NSInputStream *stream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:data];
    
    TransportBlockHeaderS transportBlockHeader;
    uint32_t len = sizeof(transportBlockHeader);
    [data getBytes:&transportBlockHeader length:len];
    //[stream read:(uint8_t*)&transportBlockHeader maxLength:sizeof(TransportBlockHeaderS)];
`
Ops, unreadable. How do I do?

Comment: Sorry -- there were two errors in the original sample. 1) You have to open a stream before you can read it; 2) you probably want to check that the result of the read is greater than 0, not greater or equal (else you'll never get out of the loop). Code above should work now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean, equivalent? `appendBytes` adds while getBytes gets, they're complete opposites. This is a nice method I use to get bytes when there's different data in the buffer. It shows a nice use of `getBytes:range:`

```
UInt16 anUInt16;
float aFloat;

int position = 0;

[data getBytes:&anUInt16 range:NSMakeRange(position, sizeof(UInt16))];
position += sizeof(UInt16);

[data getBytes:&aFloat range:NSMakeRange(position, sizeof(float))];
position += sizeof(float);
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `-[NSData getBytes:range:]`, which lets you specify the range of data that you want to read from the buffer. Another option is `-[NSData subdataWithRange:]`, which actually returns another `NSData` instance that contains only the bytes in the specified range.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.

If you need to get bytes from a specific offset, simply use the `getBytes:range:` method.

```
- ( void )getBytes: ( void * )buffer range: ( NSRange )range;
```

For instance:

```
char buf[ 4 ];

// Get 4 bytes from offset 2
[ dataObject getBytes: buf range: NSMakeRange( 2, 4 ) ];
```

If you're looking for `appendBytes`, then use **[NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html)**, which inherits from NSData and adds mutability options, just as `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.

```
- ( void )appendBytes: ( const void * )bytes length: ( NSUInteger )length;
```

You can get a `NSMutableData` from a `NSData` using the `mutableCopy` method. Note that you own the resulting object.

```
NSMutableData * mData;

mData = [ dataObject mutableCopy ];

[ mData appendBytes: ( const void * )"abcd" length: 4 ];
[ mData release ]
```